# Combining C and Python functions in a module

Tags: python, cpython

I have a C extension module, to which I would like to add some Python utility functions. Is there a recommended way of doing this?

For example:

```
import my_module

my_module.super_fast_written_in_C()
my_module.written_in_Python__easy_to_maintain()
```

I'm primarily interested in Python 2.x.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The usual way of doing this is: mymod.py contains the utility functions written in Python, and imports the goodies in the _mymod module which is written in C and is imported from _mymod.so or _mymod.pyd. For example, look at .../Lib/csv.py in your Python distribution.

Comment: csv.py is a really helpful example

Answer (score 5):

Prefix your native extension with an underscore.
Then, in Python, create a wrapper module that imports that native extension and adds some other non-native routines on top of that.

Answer (score 1):

The existing answers describe the method most often used: it has the potential advantage of allowing pure-Python (or other-language) implementations on platforms in which the compiled C extension is not available (including Jython and IronPython).

In a few cases, however, it may not be worth splitting the module into a C layer and a Python layer just to provide a few extras that are more sensibly written in Python than in C. For example, [gmpy](http://code.google.com/p/gmpy/source/browse/trunk/src/gmpy.c) (lines 7113 ff at this time), in order to enable pickling of instances of `gmpy`'s type, uses:

```
copy_reg_module = PyImport_ImportModule("copy_reg");
if (copy_reg_module) {
    char* enable_pickle =
        "def mpz_reducer(an_mpz): return (gmpy.mpz, (an_mpz.binary(), 256))\n"
        "def mpq_reducer(an_mpq): return (gmpy.mpq, (an_mpq.binary(), 256))\n"
        "def mpf_reducer(an_mpf): return (gmpy.mpf, (an_mpf.binary(), 0, 256))\n"
        "copy_reg.pickle(type(gmpy.mpz(0)), mpz_reducer)\n"
        "copy_reg.pickle(type(gmpy.mpq(0)), mpq_reducer)\n"
        "copy_reg.pickle(type(gmpy.mpf(0)), mpf_reducer)\n"
    ;
    PyObject* namespace = PyDict_New();
    PyObject* result = NULL;
    if (options.debug)
        fprintf(stderr, "gmpy_module imported copy_reg OK\n");
    PyDict_SetItemString(namespace, "copy_reg", copy_reg_module);
    PyDict_SetItemString(namespace, "gmpy", gmpy_module);
    PyDict_SetItemString(namespace, "type", (PyObject*)&PyType_Type);
    result = PyRun_String(enable_pickle, Py_file_input,
                          namespace, namespace);
```

If you want those few extra functions to "stick around" in your module (not necessary in this example case), you would of course use your module object as built by `Py_InitModule3` (or whatever other method) and its `PyModule_GetDict` rather than a transient dictionary as the namespace in which to `PyRun_String`. And of course there are more sophisticated approaches than to `PyRun_String` the `def` and `class` statements you need, but, for simple enough cases, this simple approach may in fact be sufficient.

Comment: Thanks: I was interested to see how this could be done, as well as the more common way.